# Unable to parse trademark symbol in XML using XPath

Tags: java, xpath, special-characters

Im trying to parse an XML file in Java and some lines contains an HTML symbol & #153; Still, when I do

```
((String) myXPath.evaluate(node, STRING));
```

I get square symbol instead of ™. My machine is Linux and XML encoding is UTF-8. I can't understand how to properly encode this exact symbol. & #8482; is encoded perfectly well...

I create a Document instance in a following way:

```
File xmlFile = new File(path);
FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileIS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML entity & # 153 represents the character with Unicode codepoint 153, which is some unprintable control character. It isn't a trademark symbol. 153 might be a trademark symbol in some Microsoft Windows character set, but that's irrelevant on the web. You need to use the Unicode codepoint which is 8482 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol

Note that the numbers used in HTML entity references have nothing to do with the file encoding. In fact, that's the whole point of using them - they survive changes of encoding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I figured that out also and just replaced all of 153 with 8482. For some reason XML was created with 153 and this is was the only option to parse it correctly.